# Phalcon sort data in relation

Tags: php, relationship, phalcon

I want to use a model to query data so I am defining the model relations like this:

In Categories

```
    $this->hasManyToMany(
        "id",
        "App\\Models\\CategoriesContents",
        "category_id",
        "content_id",
        "App\\Models\\Contents",
        "id",
        ["alias" => "contents"]
    );
```

In CategoriesContents

```
    $this->belongsTo(
        "category_id",
        "App\\Models\\Categories",
        "id",
        ["alias" => "category"]
    );

    $this->belongsTo(
        "content_id",
        "App\\Models\\Contents",
        "id",
        ["alias" => "content"]
    );
```

In Contents

```
    $this->hasManyToMany(
        "id",
        "App\\Models\\CategoriesContents",
        "content_id",
        "category_id",
        "App\\Models\\Categories",
        "id",
        ["alias" => "categories"]
    );
```

I have to order by name, the name in the contents table and I have a condition in the category table.

Does anyone know how to query a relation with a default `where` and `order by` clause?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full example of relation with custom parameters:

```
    $this->hasMany('id', 'Models\News', 'category_id', [
        'alias' => 'news',
        'reusable' => true,
        'params' => [
            'order' => 'id ASC',
            'conditions' => 'is_active = :is_active:',
            'bind' => [
                'is_active' => 1
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

There are more ways in **[the documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.0/reference/model-relationships.html#magic-getters-vs-explicit-methods)**.

Your first relation with ordering and where clause would look like this:

```
$this->hasManyToMany(
    "id",
    "App\\Models\\CategoriesContents",
    "category_id",
    "content_id",
    "App\\Models\\Contents",
    "id",
    [
        "alias" => "contents",
        "params" => [
            'order' => 'App\\Models\\Contents.title ASC',
            'conditions' => 'condition = :conditionParam:',
            'bind' => [
                'conditionParam' => $something
            ]
        ]
    ]
);
```

Comment: I don't get you idea. Can you explain more how to use?

Comment: Just add the `params` parameter to the relation you want. There you can order and add conditions. Updated my answer above.

Comment: I think it not same thing what I want. actually I want to get contest data and order by field title in table content and I have to where condition in category field.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution but I don't think it the best way
I add this function in contents model

```
public function find_extended($paramsMain, $paramsRelated, $limit=30, $offset=10)
{
    //Define output
    $outputs        = [];
    $index = 0;
    $contents = self::find($paramsMain);
    foreach($contents as $content)
    {
        $contentData = $content->toArray();
        $categories = $content->getCategories($paramsRelated)->toArray(); // use above parameters to search and sort as you wish
        if (!empty($categories)) {
            $contentData["categories"] = $categories;

            if ($index >= ($limit+$offset)) {
                return $outputs;
            }

            if ($index >= $offset) {
                $outputs[] = $contentData;
            }
            $index++;


        }

    }
    return $outputs;
}
```

Comment: Just add order parameter here `$contents = self::find($paramsMain)` ? There is no logic in selecting $content and then trying to sort by content title in other relation?